# "Not all… some more than others" in same sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation

> **Not all succeeded, of course – some more than others.**
>   Meanwhile, each had to make sure of his constituency while making equally sure that his opposite number had control of his.

Does it mean: of course, some of them were more successful than others?

Comment: Yes.  It means that some were more successful than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Some were more successful than others.